# OOP Design - Where/When do you Validate properties?

Tags: php, validation, oop

I have read a few books on OOP DDD/PoEAA/Gang of Four and none of them seem to cover the topic of validation - it seems to be always assumed that data is valid.

I gather from the answers to this post ([OOP Design Question - Validating properties](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1651964/153923)) that a client should only attempt to set a **valid** property value on a domain object.

This person has asked a similar question that remains unanswered: http://bytes.com/topic/php/answers/789086-php-oop-setters-getters-data-validation#post3136182

So how do you ensure it is valid? 
Do you have a 'validator method' alongside every getter and setter?

- isValidName()
- setName()
- getName()

I seem to be missing some key basic knowledge about OOP data validation - can you point me to a book that covers this topic in detail? - ie. covering different types of validation / invariants/ handling feedback / to use Exceptions or not etc

Comment: Just to add that, after some more research, i found this useful: http://devcity.net/Articles/381/1/article.aspx

Answer (score 10):

In my experience, the validation occurs where there is human/user input. And this usually happens where you allow through your method to change something. In your example, I would go for validation for the method:

```
setName()
```

So It happens where you allow input of values/setting values which turns out to be **setter methods.**

Answer (score 4):

It's important to distinguish between valid in the sense of a domain object's invariants (which must always be satisfied) and what some people call "[contextual validation."](http://devlicio.us/blogs/casey/archive/2009/03/11/ddd-invariants-or-contextual-validation.aspx) For example, is a customer with a negative bank account "invalid?" No, but they may not be authorized to perform certain kinds of transactions. That's *contextual validation*, in contrast to "every customer entity must have a non-null ID," which is a different type of validation altogether.

One effective technique to enforce invariants is to distinguish classes that represent user input from domain objects and don't expose unrestricted mutators (simple set accessors, for example) on your domain objects.

For example, if you have a `Student` domain object, don't manipulate it directly in the user interface. Instead of creating `Student` instances, your views create `StudentBuilder` instances that model what you need to construct a valid `Student` domain object.

Next, you have classes that validate builder instances conform to the domain object's invariants, and a factories that takes accept builders and can transform them into valid domain objects. (You can also introduce contextual validation strategies at this step as appropriate.)

Comment: Yes this seems to make sense. I have kind of being doing this by creating a 'specification object' or 'data cage' to hold incoming data - but had previously been unsure about it.

Answer (score 3):

Each object should make sure that its internal state is consistent, so validation is best done before the internal state is modified - in the object's setter methods.

Answer (score 3):

An important part of the OOP is too always keep your object in a valid state. Therefore, validation should be done after an input that could modify the object.

It's always good to validate data comming from properties/set, parameters to functions and constructor.

Comment: "An important part of the OOP is to always keep your object in a valid state" - I like this, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you control the code that uses your class, then you should be validating before even attempting to manipulate the object's variables (through the public properties).  If you are anticipating a scenario where you don't know how your class is to be used, then yes, you should validate within the property, that's more or less what they are for.  Obviously this assumes the definition of "is a valid name" is a static business rule inherent to the object.

Validating on both levels is of course, the safest route to go.

Comment: Yes the definition of 'isValid' is quite a confusing area too. The question seems to need some context in order to be reliable - i am finding myself writing things like : Order->IsValidOrderAccordingToPaymentStrategy()

Was hoping to hear about a classic book on this topic that everyone but me seems to have read.

Comment: Validating in more than one place seems like a bad idea. You've got duplicate code to maintain, for one thing. Plus, conceptually, if you've got a Cow object, the cow should know what constitutes valid food input - you don't want every plant in the world validating itself as acceptable cow food. Let the cow decide that.

Comment: But you wouldn't necessarily want to put your Cow into a pasture full of poisonous mushrooms, even if reasonably sure your Cow wouldn't eat them. :)

Answer (score 2):

This depends on your style of programming, as Wikipedia has more detailed explanations I will just scratch the surface and link to Wikipedia. (Yes, I'm THAT lazy. :-))

NOTE: All of this does NOT apply to user input. You have to validate it in either way. I'm just talking about the business logic classes which should not be coupled with the user input in any way. :-)

- Defensive

As mentioned by others, you will enforce every property to its bounds. I often threw runtime exceptions (Java) to indicate those failures.

[Wikipedia on Defensive Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming)

- By Contract

You document the requirements of your code and assume, for example, the values passed to your setters are valid regarding to the defined contract. This saves you a lot of boilerplate code. But bug hunting will be a little more difficult when an illegal value was  given.

[Wikipedia on Design by Contract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_by_Contract)

Comment: i found the Design By Contract (TM) info very useful - particularly the idea of 'failing hard' which seems to be a running theme of all these answers. Make the supplier's job as easy as possible and make the client decide what to do when the value is rejected.

Answer (score 1):

In short, always validate. In long, perform your validations all together at once, not 'along the way'. This will help your code remain streamlined and help debugging confusion.